# How to find every instance was created in today when field is LocalDateTime in JPA?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have a entity like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PAYMENT")
public class PaymentSummary {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "payment_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "date_created", nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "webOrder_id")
    private WebOrder webOrder;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "payment_type")
    private PaymentType paymentType;

    @Column(name = "amount")
    private Double amount;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
}
```

and i have repository for this entity

```
@Repository
public interface PaymentRepository extends JpaRepository<PaymentSummary, Long> {
    List<PaymentSummary> findAllByCreatedDate(LocalDateTime localDate); 
}
```

Later i want to retrieve every payment was created in today

```
List<PaymentSummary> payments = paymentRepository.findAllByCreatedDate(LocalDateTime.now());
```

And it return null, i know because i pass LocalDateTime.now(), so it will find exact by Date-minus-second . I want to list all today payment , and still want to keep LocalDateTime createdDate, how can i handle this situation , do i need to write native query , or JPA support this ? 
Thank you.

Comment: FYI, `LocalDateTime` is exactly the *wrong* class to be using here. That class lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So it cannot represent a moment, is not a point on the timeline. Search Stack Overflow to learn about `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, and `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: i just want use this class to keep track when instance is created and store it in database, i retrieve it late when i want, so i think LocalDateTime suitable, do i correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to store the date of the payment (year, month, day in month), and don't need time information (hour, minutes,...), you need to change `LocalDateTime` for `LocalDate` on your entity.

This way, you would have:

```
List<PaymentSummary> findAllByCreatedDate(LocalDate localDate);
```

And, using:

```
List<PaymentSummary> payments = paymentRepository.findAllByCreatedDate(LocalDate.now());
```

Would work.

If you need to store the date, and also the time information, you would need to use something like this:

```
List<PaymentSummary> findAllByCreatedDateBetween(LocalDateTime startDateTime, LocalDateTime endDateTime);
```

And call it with something like:

```
// 2020-04-12T00:00.000
LocalDateTime startDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.now() , LocalTime.MIN);
// 2020-04-12T23:59.999
LocalDateTime endDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.now() , LocalTime.MAX);

List<PaymentSummary> payments = paymentRepository.findAllByCreatedDateBetween(startDateTime, endDateTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

It will return `null` because `LocalDateTime.now()` will create the current date and time. In your case I think you need to return by date only

Comment: how can i do it with JPA ?